# (spotify:1): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: unix

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, docker, gtk

I try to run the [spotify docker container](https://hub.docker.com/r/jess/spotify/~/dockerfile/). I have docker 1.11.2 installed on Ubuntu 14.04 VM.
I'm on MAC and I'm using SSH to connect with my VM.
It's working fine but when I try to run the docker container I get an error:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-virtual-machine:~$ docker run -it -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix -e DISPLAY=unix$DISPLAY -v /dev/snd:/dev/snd --privileged --name spotify jess/spotify

(spotify:1): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: unix
```

How can I fix this? I tried already some things I read on the internet like:
edit `~/.xinitrc` and put the following in it:

```
#! /bin/bash
xhost +localhost &
```

Also tried to ssh to my ubuntu in the following way:
`ssh ubuntu@IP -X` and

```
ssh ubuntu@IP -Y
```

Comment: Does the server even have local graphics?

Comment: You could try [this](http://people.csail.mit.edu/wentzlaf/faq/ssh_X.html) for X over SSH.

Comment: Yes it has a graphical interface

Comment: a container usually doesn't (at least I never heard of something like that), I came here by google. Realized I was in a terminal on the server after reading your question...